# Story Identification: science fiction. Single human soul

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story centres on a detective or investigator who is strangely good at solving murders. The central idea is that if time and space are no obstacle, then only one human soul needs to have ever existed.

The twist is that as each incarnation progresses, more previous lives will be remembered until in the story the first to start to remember meets the very last life to be lived.

Comment: When did you read this? In English? Paperback? Hardbook? Was this one short story in an anthology? Multiple stories on the same theme?

Comment: So not "[The Egg](http://www.galactanet.com/oneoff/theegg_mod.html)" then?